# How do I resolve the pygraphviz error on mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, pygraphviz

I'm having trouble installing pygraphviz and I'm using Anaconda on macOS Monterey.

I already had graphviz on Anaconda. I then did

```
brew install graphviz
```

and then

```
pip install pygraphviz
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
    Collecting pygraphviz
  Using cached pygraphviz-1.7.zip (118 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pygraphviz
  Building wheel for pygraphviz (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-4fuwg_2b
       cwd: /private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/
  Complete output (71 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/testing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_close.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
  running egg_info
  writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
  warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
  warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
  writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  running build_ext
  building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1756:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        0,                                    /* tp_print */
        ^
  /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
      ^
  /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1923:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        0,                                    /* tp_print */
        ^
  /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
      ^
  /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2711:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
  #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  2 warnings and 1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
    Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-record-pnja99aw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pygraphviz
         cwd: /private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/
    Complete output (71 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/agraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/testing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_scraper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_readwrite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_string.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_node_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_drawing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_subgraph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_close.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_edge_attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_clear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_attribute_defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    copying pygraphviz/tests/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/tests
    running egg_info
    writing pygraphviz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1756:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          0,                                    /* tp_print */
          ^
    /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:1923:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          0,                                    /* tp_print */
          ^
    /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
        ^
    /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2711:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found
    #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-install-zr2twxnl/pygraphviz_e78bc2c823034812a5ffbd6ef61160d7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/j5/z34rlnbj2l94p1hh0x_hkkjw0000gn/T/pip-record-pnja99aw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/susiekim4/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/pygraphviz Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried `pip3 install`, `pip install cgraph`, and the other solutions.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 42):

On Mac, you must pass the path of the install directory so the wheel compiler can find the graphviz header and library files. Here's how:

Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install graphviz:

```bash
brew install graphviz
```

Get the install directory:

```bash
brew --prefix graphviz
```

Set `GRAPHVIZ_DIR` to where it was installed:

```bash
export GRAPHVIZ_DIR="[INSTALL PATH HERE]"
```

Install graphviz specifying the path:

If *using* `pip` *23.2 or later*:

```bash
export GRAPHVIZ_DIR="$(brew --prefix graphviz)"
pip install pygraphviz \
    --global-option=build_ext \
    --global-option="-I$GRAPHVIZ_DIR/include" \
    --global-option="-L$GRAPHVIZ_DIR/lib"
```

If using *an earlier version* of `pip`:

```bash
export GRAPHVIZ_DIR="$(brew --prefix graphviz)"
pip install pygraphviz \
    --config-settings=--global-option=build_ext \
    --config-settings=--global-option="-I$GRAPHVIZ_DIR/include" \
    --config-settings=--global-option="-L$GRAPHVIZ_DIR/lib"
```

With these additions, the package should be compiled and installed successfully:

```
Collecting pygraphviz
  Using cached pygraphviz-1.11.zip (120 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pygraphviz
  Building wheel for pygraphviz (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for pygraphviz: filename=pygraphviz-1.11-cp311-cp311-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl size=100586 sha256=0d6e56168321d335706a6c6789a006b8d2831bbd32b1cd28bd8fb2238122f73b
  Stored in directory: .../pip/wheels/c8/03/73/b754941d55845a8b326f6de528bc70e65774838c76effa6d51
Successfully built pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
Successfully installed pygraphviz-1.11
```

Comment: If `/opt/homebrew/*` not found use `/usr/local/Cellar/*` or `/usr/local/opt/*` as the  GRAPHVIZ_DIR

Comment: To get the GRAPHVIZ_DIR, you can do `brew info graphviz` and it should show where the package was installed.

Comment: Just for the record: This answer worked for me in June 2022,  Mac OS 12.3.1, pip 22.1.2, graphviz 3.0.0, and pygraphviz 1.9.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  In case you didn't use brew, you can get similar info out with `mdfind -name cgraph.h`.  Which, in my case, returned that I installed it with brew after all (most of my installs are with macport):  `/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.50.0/include/graphviz/cgraph.h`

Comment: MacOs with ARM processors: arch -x86_64 brew install graphviz

Comment: Worked for me, but it seems it will have to be modified soon as I get a deprecation warning: `DEPRECATION: --build-option and --global-option are deprecated. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use --config-settings.`

Answer (score 15):

For me it worked using this:

```bash
python -m pip install \
    --global-option=build_ext \
    --global-option="-I$(brew --prefix graphviz)/include/" \
    --global-option="-L$(brew --prefix graphviz)/lib/" \
    pygraphviz
```

Comment: Assuming `brew install graphviz` was run, this is the best answer.

Comment: Not exactly, since the answer by @danielm also considers earlier pip versions. The one with `--config-settings` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use **python3.12** and this is what worked for me(thanks to @Olshansky)
after `brew install graphviz`:

```
python3.12 -m pip install \
--config-setting="--global-option=build_ext" \
--config-setting="--global-option=-I$(brew --prefix graphviz)/include/" \
--config-setting="--global-option=-L$(brew --prefix graphviz)/lib/" \
pygraphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy  /opt/homebrew/bin/dot to /usr/local/bin/dot, restart the visual studio code and done!

Command:

```
sudo cp /opt/homebrew/bin/dot /usr/local/bin/dot
```

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend the only solution that worked for me from [azabraoo](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/11#issuecomment-1243897424):

```bash
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I$(brew --prefix graphviz)/include/" --global-option="-L$(brew --prefix graphviz)/lib/" pygraphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a pyenv running python 3.11.0, pip 24.0

When I try to `$pip install pygraphviz` I get the same error:

> pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:3020:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found

However for me, I get

> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

instead of

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

(what you got). But I believe it can be resolved in the same manner.
So what I did was

`$pip install pygraphviz --verbose > error.log 2>&1`

This is to get the error into the file so I can search through it (you can name 'error.log' however you like). Then I did `view error.log` and searched for `/clang` (in your case, you can do `/gcc`). Then I found this:

> `clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DSWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR -I/Users/royyc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/include/python3.11 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-13.0-arm64-cpython-311/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o`

Made note of

> `-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/ MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`

The `-I` means include path while downloading pygraphviz. So it will look into this path to find the 'cgraph.h' file

The issue was that my cgraph.h file is located in these places (use `$locate cgraph.h`):

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/plugin/include/cgraph.h
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/10.0.1/include/graphviz/cgraph.h

Since we got the fatal error that 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found, I did

> `sudo cp -R /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/10.0.1/include/graphviz /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`

to copy all the files in

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/10.0.1/include/graphviz

(that includes cgraph.h and other files) to

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

since this is (`-I`) included in the path during build.

That resolved the issue for me:)